# Load a package temporarily

Tags: packages

I want to use one function from a built in package (specifically `CCompilers[]` from `"CCompilerDriver`"`). It seems unnecessary to load in the whole package for the rest of my session, how can I do this only temporarily?

Is something like the following sufficient for this?

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"];
compilers = CCompilers[];
ClearAll["CCompilerDriver`"];
```

Or is there some kind of preferred or standard method that's more complete?
I think I have something in mind which would work a bit like `Block`

Comment: OK thanks, I can use this to do what I want to. It would also be cool to have an environment like `Block` which loads a package only temporarily. I don't think the thread you linked answers that question.

Comment: In short, packages cannot be unloaded.  "Unnecessary" does not seem like a good motivation to want to do this. If you explain your specific concerns, perhaps we can suggest a way to address them.  So, what do you expect to gain by unloading the package?

Comment: If you just want to prevent name pollution, then either: 1) remove the package context from `$ContextPath` when you're done (this does not unload) or 2) prevent adding it to the context path in the first place by loading the package using ``Block[{$ContextPath}, Needs["SomePackage`"]]``.  If you do this, you will need to use fully qualified names such as ``CCompileDriver`CCompilers[]``.  `ClearAll` seems like a bad idea to me, and could cause breakage much more easily than what I suggested.

Comment: OK thanks Szabolcs, I've decided to go with your solution of 'stop worring about it'

Comment: You could also use ``Block[{$ContextPath},
 Needs["CCompilerDriver`"];
 CCompilerDriver`CCompilers[]
 ]``. Just be sure to use `Needs` and not `Get`, to prevent double-loading.